# button alignment in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have declared the button as,

```
<button id='submitExpectedJ0' type='button'></button>
```

I need to align it to right, i tried with

```
style= 'float: right;'
```

on the widget ID it didnt work,
In chrome its shown as,

```
 <span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton dijitButtonHover dijitHover" role="presentation" widgetid="submitExpectedJ0">
```

May be the style is overriden by this class.

How to align the button to right?

Comment: A Fiddle would help.

Comment: Does my answer help you? If not, could you explain what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap your button in a `div` or `span`, setting the width of the `div`/`span` to 100% and include `text-align:right` as part of the style. something like:

```
<div style="width:100%;text-align:right">
    <button id='submitExpectedJ0' type='button'></button>
</div>
```

The `float;right` may also work once you have the wrapping included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
#submitExpectedJ0 {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :

```css
.dijit {
    float: right;  
}
```

```html
<span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton dijitButtonHover dijitHover" role="presentation" widgetid="submitExpectedJ0">To right</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#id {
float:right;
```

}

this should work 
i run my css  on firefox and it works!